# Facebook is not allowed to enter key hash

Tags: android, facebook

Hi I got keyhash and i want to insert it into keyhash of Facebook apps page but they are not allowing me to enter please any body help me how to resolve that issue

I am uploading that picture my key hash : Iu2kwPnylF8OKtVqPSY/r6kBGG8

[image]

when i try to click on save changes it will still not allowing me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generates keyhas with this code:

```
    try {

           PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("Your.packet.name",PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

           for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
              MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
              md.update(signature.toByteArray());
              Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
           }

    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

If you already previously generated more usher in the code that you have shown keyhash ultimately lacks the symbol " = "